# the auth_key of yii2 is'nt interference in cookie base

Tags: authentication, yii2, remember-me

I have problem with auth_key , I have login form and it's work correctly without remember me and with remember me , but I read yii document , in that document wrote about remember me work with id  and auth_key for create cookie to stay user in long time , i check the framework code and in there have three parameters (id, auth_key, expire_time()) i save auth_key in user table and it's code here

```
public function generateAuthKey()
{
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}
```

but i have problem , it's if a user login in site and i go to the user table and change the auth_key field , and now if user refresh the page it must be throw out the site because it's auth key is changed , but the user stay login in site , where is problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use of `auth_key` is to authenticate the user by cookie (user don't have to put login data again). When you choose to be remembered at Login, this is how you are remembered. The system has to identify and login you somehow. It won't log out user if u change it.

Comment: in document said:
getAuthKey(): it returns a key used to verify cookie-based login. The key is stored in the login cookie and will be later compared with the server-side version to make sure the login cookie is valid.
validateAuthKey(): it implements the logic for verifying the cookie-based login key.

Comment: how can i access to auth_key , i want to terminate user session , if user checked remember me it,s created cookie "_identity" and i want to change auth_key to user after refresh page throw out of panel

Comment: Yeah, and that's what it does exacly. Cookie-based login allows user to 'autologin` without providing again login data when they are logged out. U can't terminate user session by this.

Comment: okey , please help me , how can i terminate that kind of user , like telegram terminate session , is there any ways to do this?

Comment: Try to use DB sessions: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-dbsession.html  So U can operate on SQL queries.

Comment: yes , i save sessions in mongodb , and it's work prefect with user than don't checked the remember me , and they are loged out after i remove their sessions but if user checked remember me i cant throw the user out form login because for cookie , after i deleted his session after refresh page , created new session for him

Comment: So delete session AND change auth_key?

Comment: i just delete session but, perhaps it's my problem , but in normal way i change auth_key in phpmyadmin for test and refresh page but user still stay in site

Comment: U have to delete session and change auth_key in one action, not delete session, do something on web page, change auth_key, do something on web page.

Comment: thank you , i will check this and , tell the news here

Comment: thanks , i removed session and change auth key in user table and it's work correctly

Comment: hi , i have another problem , that way work but when i remove auth key because auth_key is shared for all of user all of them removed , for this : in next comment:
i save my session in mongodb session , for this problem i save auth_key in mogodb near session id
but there is problem by every refresh page the auth_key is changed in mongo and when i deleted the session row for one user he is still login in site

Comment: 'session' => [
'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Session',
'writeCallback' => function($session)
{
return [
'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
'agent' => Yii::$app->request->getUserAgent(),
'ip' => Yii::$app->request->getUserIP(),
'auth_key' => Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(),
];
}
],

i check my auth key like this
public function getAuthKey()
Yii::$app->session->open();
    $query = new Query();
    $query->select(['auth_key'])
        ->from('cache')
        ->where(['id'=> Yii::$app->session->id ]);
    $row = $query->one();
    return $row['auth_key'];
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the key yourself in the "ValidateAutney" method, but this will be a bad practice, it is better to set the session time.

Comment: thanks I do it , i have save session in db with auth_key value and it solved

Comment: excusme , could you check the comments of Yupik i have problem in 3 last comments

Answer (score 0):

```
'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Session',
        'writeCallback' => function($session)
        {
            return [
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                'agent' => Yii::$app->request->getUserAgent(),
                'ip' => Yii::$app->request->getUserIP(),
                'auth_key' => Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(),
            ];
        }
    ],

    public function getAuthKey()
{

    Yii::$app->session->open();

    $query = new Query();

    $query->select(['auth_key'])
        ->from('cache')
        ->where(['id'=> Yii::$app->session->id ]);
    $row = $query->one();
    return $row['auth_key'];
}
```